# From .NET verify a dll has valid signature and has not been modified

Tags: c#, .net, dll, x509certificate2

My c# .NET program accesses a c++ library.

The library is signed with a certificate and is in the same folder as the program.

At runtime, before i load the c++ library, i want to make sure the library is really mine and has not been tampered with.

I have been able to get the certificate from my dll and verify the certificate :

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filename));
Console.WriteLine(cert.Issuer);`
cert.Verify();`
```

This tells me the file certificate is ok, but if I then hexedit my file and run my program again, the certificate still validates ok.

Where can I find in the certificate the hash of my library (not the hash of the certificate) and how can I create the hash of my library to compare them so I can detect the file being tampered with?

I suspect it should be simple, maybe I overlooked something.

Answer (score 0):

PInvoke the native Windows API `WinVerifyTrust`, which is documented by Microsoft at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208(v=vs.85).aspx) with a sample in C.

There might be managed examples by others if you use a search engine.

Comment: I had seen mention of WinVerifyTrust in the past but it was in a post from 2008 so i hoped that .NET library would have included something by now. The issue with WinVerifyTrust is that as it's a native library, i need to DllImport it and guess someone could hijack wintrust.dll too.

Comment: .NET hasn’t changed much and it wont wrap everything. The concern you have on hijacking makes sense, but do you want to implement everything then on your own?

Comment: An example was found at https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust